# How to draw an arrow with a circle trajectory with animation on canvas android?

Tags: android, animation, android-canvas

guys
I try to implement an black arrow which is on head of arc. The arrow animates with the arc, and has circle trajectory. I already implement the red arc with animation based on different values.
Please see the attachment.
How can I implement the black arrow on top of red arc? since if I do the same way as red arc animation, the black arrow will print the trajectory which is not desired.

Thanks in advance!
Leon

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you need is Canvas.

Here is example.

This is the your draw class:

```
public class CircleView   extends View
{
    public CircleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        path = new Path();
        paint = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        float angle = 270;

        float radius = canvas.getWidth()/3;
        float x = canvas.getWidth()/2;
        float y = canvas.getHeight()/2;
        final RectF oval = new RectF();

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(25);

        oval.set(x - radius, y - radius, x + radius,y + radius);

        // Draw circle
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawArc(oval, 135, angle, false, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawArc(oval, angle, 405-angle, false, paint);

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        float l = 1.2f;
        float a = angle*(float)Math.PI/180;
        // Draw arrow
        path.moveTo(x+ (float)Math.cos(a) *radius, y + (float)Math.sin(a) * radius);
        path.lineTo(x+ (float)Math.cos(a+0.1) *radius*l, y + (float)Math.sin(a+0.1) * radius*l);
        path.lineTo(x+ (float)Math.cos(a-0.1) *radius*l, y + (float)Math.sin(a-0.1) * radius*l);
        path.lineTo(x+ (float)Math.cos(a) *radius, y + (float)Math.sin(a) * radius);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
    private Path path;
    private Paint paint;
}
```

This is activity for it:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new CircleView(this));
    }
}
```

For angle == 200 you will see image like this:

[image: angle == 200]

Working copy for IntelliJ Idea: https://github.com/weerf/android_circle

Comment: Hi, Kirill. Thanks for your reply. I use this code in animation, the black arrow get drawn on the way . What I really need is to just show one arrow on top of red arc animation. (right now there are multiple arrows get drawn along with animation process). Another thing is the black arrow shape is not the same as I described in graph. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The black arrow is just a freeform polygon.Im my response it have three vertices , and in the question it have four vertices. And one more difference - I have not set a flag ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG.
If the question is this:
add one vertex to arrow, and set the flag ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG

Comment: I correct it on https://github.com/weerf/android_circle/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/podlivaev/circle/CircleView.java             Image will be like https://github.com/weerf/android_circle/blob/master/screen.png

Comment: Hi, Kirill. Thanks for your help. I did set ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG, and the remaining issue is around arrow animation part. I use applyTransformation from Animation and inside this function, I use requestLayout() for different angles to do animation. So the arrow got drawn each time and end up with drawing multiple arrows on the arc. I will handle this and let you know the result.

Comment: Hi, Kirill. There was a bug in my code. I should new a path each time when  onDraw() get called, and use that path for drawing arrow. I apologize for confusion. Thanks again.